# Trying to access object in an array of objects but only one object is saved

Tags: c++, arrays, object, go-back-n

I'm trying to implement the GoBackN ARQ for a class. I'm attempting to read a file, break it up into packets of 30 characters and then store the packets in an array of packets. All of these packets are objects of the `class packet`.

Currently, this code compiles and runs however when I access the array of packets, at index 0 of the array I receive the last and most recent packet. When I attempt to access index 1, I expected a different packet, however, the packets are the same in all of the indices.

Why is the data in all of my packets the same?

```
int numPackets = 0;
packet *packetArray[30];

void addPacket(packet *p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        if (packetArray[i])
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            packetArray[i] = p;
            numPackets++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argumentCount, char *argumentVariables[]) {

    char buffer[1024];

    std::ifstream infile (argumentVariables[1], std::ifstream::binary);
    infile.seekg (0, infile.end);
    int lengthOfFile = infile.tellg();
    infile.seekg (0, infile.beg);

    int iterator = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        if (lengthOfFile > 30)
        {
            bzero(buffer, 1024);
            infile.read(buffer, 30);
            lengthOfFile -= 30;
            addPacket(new packet(1, iterator, strlen(buffer), buffer));
            iterator++;
        }
        else
        {
            bzero(buffer, 1024);
            infile.read(buffer, 30);
            addPacket(new packet(1, iterator, strlen(buffer), buffer));
            break;
        }
    }

    packet * sendpckt = packetArray[0];
    sendpckt->serialize(sendPayload);
    printf("%s\n", sendPayload);

    infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Constructor code of the `class packet`.

```
packet::packet(int t, int s, int l, char * d){
    type = t;
    seqnum = s;
    length = l;
    data = d;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show the constructor code of class "packet". First I think you must add a '\0' in the end of buffer after the "infile.read(buffer, 30)", second check if you are copying the buffer or only  the address of the buffer to a "packet" member.

Comment: Constructor code added. And I'll check on those things to see if that's the problem. @lewohart

Comment: The data for the all packets is always pointing to the same buffer. Then you will always see the last value. You have to copy the data to a new buffer for each packet and don't forget to free them in the destructor.

Comment: data = new char[l]; strncpy(data, d, l);

Comment: Yeah I confirmed that by making a whole new character array. How would you suggest I go about making multiple buffers that each packet could point to?

Comment: Don't forget: packet::~packet() { delete []data; }

Comment: Thank you so much! Fixed my issue.